# Why doesn't my application see Entity Framework model updates

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have an MVC application that uses Entity Framework.  I needed to create a new stored procedure for the application to use.  I created the stored procedure in the database first so I know it exists.  Then in my project, I updated the model from the database and pulled in the new stored procedure.  Then I created a function import with a complex type and saved the model.  I have a service that is using the model and I can reference the new complex type without a problem.

The issue I run into is when running the application and hitting this stored procedure, I get an error that says "Could not find stored procedure."

The method throwing the error is here:

```
public virtual ObjectResult<E3_Assessment_GetPDFImages_Result> E3_Assessment_GetPDFImages(Nullable<int> assessmentID)
    {
        var assessmentIDParameter = assessmentID.HasValue ?
            new ObjectParameter("assessmentID", assessmentID) :
            new ObjectParameter("assessmentID", typeof(int));

        return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<E3_Assessment_GetPDFImages_Result>("E3_Assessment_GetPDFImages", assessmentIDParameter);
    }
```

Are there any additional steps I need to take to make sure the everything is updated in the Entity Framework?  I have verified the stored procedure exists in the database.  The only other thing I can think of is that the model is not seeing the new stored procedure.

UPDATE Connection String

```
<add name="AssessmentEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/AssessmentModel.csdl|res://*/AssessmentModel.ssdl|res://*/AssessmentModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=MyServer;initial catalog=MyDatabase;persist security info=True;user id=MyUser;password=MyPassowrd;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

**UPDATE**
I ran sql server profiler and found why I'm getting the error.  When the stored procedure runs it is running in the master database instead of the actual database it should run in.  Other stored procs are running in the correct database.

Why is it running in the master database instead of the database I want?

Comment: Your connection string, please!

Comment: Did you include Database name in your stored procedure? In a 'USE' tag or as part of the table name? mydatabase.mytable?

Comment: The USE statement is in the stored proc with the correct database name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to reinitialize my context before calling the stored procedure.  That is why it was using the master database.